# Example of reverse geocoding with google maps with BazingaGeocoderBundle

Tags: google-maps, symfony, reverse-geocoding

I am actually trying to make  reverse geocoding with google maps. But, I did not find any example in the documentations of BazingaGeocoderBundle.

Could you please give me an example or a link to a documentation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the documentation for the base project.

The link is on the BazingaGeocoderBundle page....

Integration of the **[Geocoder](https://github.com/geocoder-php/Geocoder)** library into Symfony2.